# jQuery Mobile - Page is not reloading

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to jQuery Mobile. I am trying to move from page #one1 to #page2. #page2 contains an address book form. If I fill something in the form and click on the back button to move to #page1 and then I again move to #page2, the form will show all the previously filled data.

I want that when I go back to #page2 all the fields be blank.

I have also tried it with putting an alert. The alert will popup the first time but it is not showing when I revisit this page again.

```
$('#page2').live('pageinit',function(event){
alert("Edit");
});
```

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

In the button that shows up #page2, don't move right away to #page2, first call a function that clears the fields. And then you can move to #page2...

Comment: i am able to clear the fields but the alert is not showing when page is reopened. The alert is showing only the first time.

Comment: Of course, since you do it on 'pageinit' --- that works only once.

Comment: but i need when ever page is loaded it will fire alert message

Comment: Pageinit should also fire each time a page is loaded: http://jsfiddle.net/Calavoow/RdUkT/2/

Comment: it is showing alert "pageinit" first time after that it redirect to page two. Now when i click on back button & again click on "Click me!" the alert message is not showing. I want when i come back to the first page again and click on the link "Click me!" it will alert each time.